# How do I select something in MYSQL without selecting it twice if its in the row

Tags: php, mysql, select

The title may sound confusing. But here's my issue. I want to show something that is displayed in the database, but it may show up in multiple rows. For example:

```
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
```

I want to display this data, but I don't want it to repeat, I just want it to show the 2s and 1s once.

What I have now:

```
$TheSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `1`="'.$profileID.'" ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 10';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change `SELECT *` to `SELECT DISTINCT *`.

Answer (score 2):

**Using DISTINCT**

`DISTINCT` allows you to remove duplicate rows from a result set. It's used like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tablename
```

Be aware that `DISTINCT` applies to all of the returned columns in the result set. So, if you are returning multiple fields, and you want to apply it to a particular field, `DISTINCT` won't be the answer.

For example, given the following data set:

```
user_id      whatever
----------------------
1            this
1            that
2            this
2            this
```

The following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, whatever
FROM tablename
```

Returns:

```
1            this
1            that
2            this
```

It only removed the duplicate `2, this` row because considering both columns, that was the only duplicate.

However, if I select a single column like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM tablename
```

I will get the following, desired, results:

```
1
2
```

**Using GROUP BY**

So, in the case where you're selecting multiple columns but want just one of the columns to be distinct, you can use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, whatever
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
```

Which gives the following results, returning just one row per distinct user_id:

```
1            this
2            this
```

Though, these results may be just as likely:

```
1            that
2            this
```

The non-grouped column's value is going to be arbitrary. In fact, MySQL 4.x won't even accept the above `GROUP BY` query. MySQL 4.x doesn't allow you to mix aggregate (grouped) and non-aggregate columns. Therefore, the following query would be preferred:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, MAX(whatever)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
```

Now, the results for the second column are not arbitrary:

```
1            this
2            this
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE `1`="'.$profileID.'" ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 10';
```

...DISTINCT is the key