# How do I retrieve data with MySQL such that I won't be getting duplicate values in a single column?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am currently working on a school system where we have a parent course and a child course (meta_courses in Moodle).

So, we have a table mdl_course_meta and it has 3 fields. Id, parent_course and child_course.

My problem is that a parent course can have many child courses so that means, for example, a parent_course = 50 can appear two times in the table which means it has 2 child courses. I just want to be able to find all the parent courses without it returning the same value twice or more times. I'm currently using this query right now which obviously doesn't do what I want:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM mdl_course_meta";
```

I am working with PHP as well by the way.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select something in MYSQL without selecting it twice if its in the row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421508/how-do-i-select-something-in-mysql-without-selecting-it-twice-if-its-in-the-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_course from mdl_course_meta
```

That should do it if you just want the course names.  One thing to keep in mind, if you want other fields this is not going to work the way you want it to(how would it know which record to choose if there are multiple records with the same parent_course and you only want one).

This approach can only be used if you only want to return the parent_courses without duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT helps to eliminate duplicates.  If a query returns a result that contains duplicate rows, you can remove duplicates to produce a result set in which every row is unique. To do this, include the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT and before the output column list.

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT parent_course FROM mdl_course_meta";
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wasn't clear. I don't want to duplicate values on a column!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want duplicate values in a **single** column, use `GROUP BY parent_course`.
In this way you are free to select any column.

Comment: Doing a select * using group by will give funny results(how will it know which child_course to return for that parent?)

Comment: $q = "SELECT parent_course FROM mdl_course_meta GROUP BY parent_course";

Would this work as opposed to having *?

Comment: @jzworkman By default the first retrieved row remains in the result. If you want to have control over what row you want to return per group, use `HAVING`.

Comment: just an fyi as well if you have a large data set, `group by` will perform more slowly(as it queries and then combines) where `select distinct` will be quicker as it modifies the query instead of combining the data afterward.

Comment: Hey thanks I'm using distinct and that works as well. I guess I'll stick with DISTINCT since it's faster then :)

Comment: And depending on your database, using group by with ambiguous columns(such as trying to select child_course as well) can result in an ambiguous column error. Just things to think about when using the two, the only time you should use `group by` instead is when you are aggregating the data of one column(such as getting a count or sum)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want distinct values for a particular column column, then you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_course_meta
GROUP BY parent_course
```

The values in the other columns will be arbitrary. This will work in MySQL 5.x.

MySQL 4.x won't let you be arbitrary, so you can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns. Instead, you'd have to do something like this, which gets a bit complicated:

```
SELECT MAX(col1), MAX(col2), parent_course, MAX(col4), ...
FROM mdl_course_meta
GROUP BY parent_course
```

This way, the values aren't arbitrary. You've specified the ones you want.